# google polyline: string out of range

Tags: google-polyline

I try to use google polyline to decode the data. My data looks like

'y`rwFpjpbMbDxB|BxAtBxAjFhDrFnDFHlBnAtBtAzBvAvFrDl@\\`MfFNHo@~CtF|BXLn@aDp@}Cp@mCfAuD\{AlKmg@@]L{@pAoG`Nup@bCoL`@gBf@eC^gBb@cBjD{P\oBVyAFgA?cAs@_QK}@Q_AYcAa@cA]i@m@w@w@q@a@WuCyAcAk@}@o@aA{@}@}@aBuBG[m@m@oEuFcAwAmB}CeDaG_FcJqAeCm@oAKe@Yu@c@aBa@cB[eBEa@fCeBlCYzGq@ZzG'

If I put this string into the code

polyline.decode('y`rwFpjpbMbDxB|BxAtBxAjFhDrFnDFHlBnAtBtAzBvAvFrDl@\\`MfFNHo@~CtF|BXLn@aDp@}Cp@mCfAuD\{AlKmg@@]L{@pAoG`Nup@bCoL`@gBf@eC^gBb@cBjD{P\oBVyAFgA?cAs@_QK}@Q_AYcAa@cA]i@m@w@w@q@a@WuCyAcAk@}@o@aA{@}@}@aBuBG[m@m@oEuFcAwAmB}CeDaG_FcJqAeCm@oAKe@Yu@c@aBa@cB[eBEa@fCeBlCYzGq@ZzG'), it gives me the data.

However, if I run the program and save the string into a list, like code[],
and run the code

polyline.decode(code[0]), the error will say:

IndexError: string index out of range

I tried many times and cannot figure the problem.Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to the escape characters in your string.

I a similar issue when copy/pasting a an encoded string from a web call into a python script as a raw string:

```
encoded_string = r"<pasted string>"
l = polyline.decode(encoded_string)

>>
>> .. IndexError: string index out of range
```

When making it a normal string (removing the 'r' qulification) it worked

```
encoded_string = "<pasted string>"
l = polyline.decode(encoded_string)
```